# Copy sqlite db from my app document folder to builtin file app folder in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I would like to backup the todo sqlite db in my app for using in other iphone app. How to export the sqlite db? I am using the library `sqlite.swift`.

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

var doumentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! NSString

var error : NSError?

let sourcePath = doumentDirectoryPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("todo.sqlite")

let destinationPath = ?(how to get builtin file app path)(how to copy to local file app?)

fileManager.copyItemAtPath(sourcePath!, toPath: destinationPath, error: &error)
```

Comment: did you get solution for exporting sqlite from app to device ?

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Xcode (8 and up, I think), open this with Window menu --> Devices. Find the device in the device list and look at the installed apps list for the device. Each app that you've built and installed on the device will be listed (and maybe some others). Select your app and click the gear menu below the list. Clicking the "Download" item on the pop-up menu will enable you to copy the app's documents, library, and other directories to your Mac.

NB: This will download an .xcappdata file. Right-clicking on that and selecting "Show Package Contents" will allow you to drill down to the actual sqlite file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to copy sqlite file programatically  to builtin file app using swift. Any suggestions welcome.